# 例外はなぜ「投げる」と言う？

Tags: 専門用語, 英語

例外 exception は、なぜ投げる throw 受け取る catch する、と呼ぶのでしょうか？
他の動詞でなくて throw/catch が使われたのはなぜでしょう。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[例外処理に関するWikipediaのページ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#History)にこんな記述がありました。

> **History**
>   Software exception handling developed in Lisp in the 1960s and 1970s. This originated in LISP 1.5 (1962), where exceptions were caught by the ERRSET keyword, which returned NIL in case of an error, instead of terminating the program or entering the debugger.[11] Error raising was introduced in MacLisp in the late 1960s via the ERR keyword.[11] This was rapidly used not only for error raising, but for non-local control flow, and thus was augmented by two new keywords, CATCH and THROW (MacLisp June 1972), reserving ERRSET and ERR for error handling. The cleanup behavior now generally called "finally" was introduced in NIL (New Implementation of LISP) in the mid- to late-1970s as UNWIND-PROTECT.[12] This was then adopted by Common Lisp. Contemporary with this was dynamic-wind in Scheme, which handled exceptions in closures. The first papers on structured exception handling were Goodenough (1975a) and Goodenough (1975b).[13] Exception handling was subsequently widely adopted by many programming languages from the 1980s onward.

なので、MacLispを設計した人に聞いてみないと、本当のところは分かりませんね。言語によっては`throw`ではなく、`raise`を使うこともあるようです。

Comment: MacLisp の設計者がたまたま選んだ用語が今も引き続き使われている、ってことですかね？ 起源はこの辺にある、ってことで解決済みにしておきます。そういや `throw` を例外以外に使うことってありましたっけ？こういうのは別トピックにしたほうがよいですよね。

Comment: 多分、最初に命名した人のセンスで決まったので、明確な回答は難しい質問ではないかと思います。ちなみに、Javaであれば`java.lang.Throwable`を継承している`java.lang.Error`も`throw`できますね。

Answer (score 2):

例外の、「例外を発生させる」、「コードを追って言って、最初にその例外を受け取れるハンドリングコードに処理をあけわたす」を上手く表す動詞が throw して catch するだったからではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

通常の関数呼び出し`call`、その戻り`return`がありますが、例外`exception`はそれらを超越して処理されるため、`throw` / `catch`なのだと理解しています。C言語には`setjmp` / `longjmp`が存在しているので`jump`は避けるべきでしょうし。

[Windowsの構造化例外](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/swezty51.aspx)だと`raise` / `except`（他に`filter`なども）が使われていますね。

Comment: 例外機構の実装に `setjmp` / `longjmp` 使っていますしね。同じ用語を使うのは混乱を招くだけですね。